# Gradle dependency constrains are not applied

Tags: java, gradle, log4j2

I have following in my Gradle config:

```
dependencies {    
    implementation "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.32"
    implementation "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.15.0"
    implementation "org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.32"
    implementation "org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.32"

    constraints {
        add("implementation", "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core") {
            version {
                strictly("[2.15")
                prefer("2.15.0")
            }
            because("CVE-2021-44228 Log4j 2 Vulnerability")
        }
        add("implementation", "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api") {
            version {
                strictly("[2.15")
                prefer("2.15.0")
            }
            because("CVE-2021-44228 Log4j 2 Vulnerability")
        }
    }
}
```

Though this config doesn't depend on log4j directly, it has some transient dependencies on log4j. And I expect that it would enforce use of version 2.15.0 or later.

But unfortunately it doesn't change anything:

```
$ gradle dependencies | grep log4j
+--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.15.0
|    \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.15.0 -> 2.13.3
.....
+--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:{strictly [2.15; prefer 2.15.0} -> 2.13.3 (c)
\--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:{strictly [2.15; prefer 2.15.0} -> 2.13.3 (c)
```

And

```
$ gradle dependencyInsight --dependency org.apache.logging.log4j

> Task :dependencyInsight 
org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.13.3
variant "compile" [
  org.gradle.status                  = release (not requested)
  org.gradle.usage                   = java-api
  org.gradle.libraryelements         = jar (compatible with: classes+resources)
  org.gradle.category                = library

  Requested attributes not found in the selected variant:
     org.gradle.dependency.bundling     = external
     org.gradle.jvm.environment         = standard-jvm
     org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type = jvm
     org.gradle.jvm.version             = 13
]
Selection reasons:
  - Selected by rule
  - By constraint : CVE-2021-44228 Log4j 2 Vulnerability

org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:{strictly [2.15; prefer 2.15.0} -> 2.13.3
\--- compileClasspath

org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.15.0 -> 2.13.3
\--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.15.0
     \--- compileClasspath
```

Why it downgrades to version 2.13.3? Even though it was set as 2.15 for `log4j-slf4j-impl` and also required by constraints.

Same result with Gradle 6.9 and 7.2

--

Upd:

For simplicity I changed the constraints to:

```
    add("implementation", "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.15.0") {
        because("CVE-2021-44228 Log4j 2 Vulnerability")
    }
    add("implementation", "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.15.0") {
        because("CVE-2021-44228 Log4j 2 Vulnerability")
    }
```

Still no effect

Comment: `[2.15,[3` - is it correct version range declaration?

Comment: Should be, as per https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/single_versions.html. Also suggested here https://twitter.com/CedricChampeau/status/1469608906196410368. 
Anyway, I tried other options including just `2.15.+`, but it doesn't change anything

Comment: twitter post suggests `[2.15,3[` but not `[2.15,[3` (the last one causes build error), btw such configuration does work for single-module project

Comment: Ah, thank you. Fixed example to just `[2.15`. In fact I was trying without `[3` part and added it (incorrectly) back just for the demo. Anyway, it doesn't work. I think I'm missing something else to actually enable it, but I don't see anything in docs that might help

Comment: I have a single module config, btw. W/o any weird configs or plugins

Comment: Turns out it was caused by https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin Which was not even needed and was just a historical artifact in that build. And it was breaking all types of version ranges, now I see that the working version is supposed to be exactly `[2.15,3[`

Answer (score 4):

The problem was caused by `io.spring.dependency-management` Gradle plugin, which was also used in that project. Removing that plugin fixed the issue.

So the fix is to remove `io.spring.dependency-management` plugin.

Also, the correct constraint *must be* following:

```
constraints {
    add("implementation", "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core") {
        version {
            strictly("[2.15,3[")
            prefer("2.15.0")
        }
        because("CVE-2021-44228 Log4j 2 Vulnerability")
    }
}
```

I.e., just `log4j-core` is enough, and version range must be exactly `[2.15,3[`

Comment: Spring has published a blog post about this as well (https://spring.io/blog/2021/12/10/log4j2-vulnerability-and-spring-boot) - in short you can override the dependency plugin with `ext['log4j2.version'] = '2.16.0'`

Answer (score 0):

This [library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.15.0) depends on `org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25`.

```
dependencies {    
    testIplementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.15.0'
}
```

There probably is no need for any `constraints`; try `mavenCentral()`? And as one can see (link above), it comes with compile, runtime and test dependencies. And when Maven Central suggests this should be `testImplementation`, this may be the correct configuration to use.

Answer (score 0):

The Gradle Team [published a workaround](https://blog.gradle.org/log4j-vulnerability) specifically for the critical Log4J bug in versions prior to 2.15.0. However, a new vulnerability has been reported that prompted the release of 2.16.0 so you should update your rules accordingly.

However, Gradle's recommended fix does not work if you're using Spring's dependency management plugin `id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "x.y.z"`.

To deal with Gradle dependencies sans Spring dependency management, simply create a plugin that sets version requirements for Log4J:

```
class Log4jConventionPlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    private val log = KotlinLogging.logger { }
    
    private val dependencies = listOf(
        "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core",
        "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl",
        "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-jul"
    )

    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        applyConstraints(project)
        applySpringDependencyManagementFix(project)
    }
    
    // apply standard Gradle constraints
    private fun applyConstraints(project: Project) {
        
        project.dependencies.constraints { constraints ->
            listOf("compileClasspath", "implementation", "runtimeOnly", "runtimeClasspath").forEach { configuration ->
                dependencies.forEach { dependency ->
                    constraints.add(configuration, dependency) { c ->
                        c.version { v ->
                            v.strictly("[2.16, 3[")
                            v.require("2.16.0")
                            v.reject("[2.0, 2.16[")
                        }
                        c.because("CVE-2021-44228: Log4j vulnerable to remote code execution")
                        log.info { "Applied log4j version constraint to $dependency for configuration $configuration" }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        log.info { "Applied log4j version constraints" }
    }

    // constraints Spring Boot dependency management constraints
    private fun applySpringDependencyManagementFix(project: Project) {
        project.plugins.findPlugin("io.spring.dependency-management") ?: return
        project.configurations.all {
            it.resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
                if (details.requested.group == "org.apache.logging.log4j") {
                    details.useVersion("2.16.+")
                }
            }
        }
        log.info { "Applied fixed Log4J resolution to Spring dependency management" }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the import for ServiceConvention  ? I'm trying to implement this solution, but I'm stuck there

Comment: Sorry @ErwanLeroux that's just a type I made you can apply in in the main plugin body. I'll update my answer to make it clearer.